# What to use instead of Putty and the vi

Tags: linux, eclipse, virtual-machine, putty

So, I got a new job and it requires a lot of VM management and editing php files on these VM's.
Anyway we use putty to log into the VM's and just linux commands to edit the files.
I figure there has to be an easier way out there. Not that I can't handle linux commands, but editing documents becomes much more cumbersome this way.
I heard there is a way to do this through eclipse, but I don't know it. 
I do not ever have the php files on my computer, so wamp wouldn't work to my knowledge.
thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can download the remote systems plugin and SSH from eclipse.

Comment: It depends on your access level. I believe you have only headless access. So putty and Vim is best for these uses. Better to learn how to use Vim. Believe me it is very interesting.

Comment: `WinSCP` and `download` the File.  Edit with `Notepad++` or whatever you prefer, and `upload` it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [RSE](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html) (Remote Systems Explorer) plugin in Eclipse.
2. You can simply create local git repository and then clone it on a remote system. This way you can work with your files locally (even when the network is down or you are on the beach) and push the changes as needed. Eclipse has a decent Git UI. You also get to keep complete change history!

Comment: So, I downloaded the Zend version of eclipse, for PHP, and downloaded RSE for it. Works great very easy to set up. Thanks for letting me know this exists. I'm a long time eclipse user so I'm happy i can go back to it. They really need to make the eclipse color themes modifiable in the eclipse program not some weird website.

Answer (score 2):

A good alternative would be to use Sublime's SFTP plugin to edit the files directly.. This is a great way to manage your code.

Download Sublime Text:
http://sublimetext.com/

Install Package Control:
https://sublime.wbond.net/

Install SFTP:
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/installation

Then you can browse the server remotely by setting up a Remote, and syncing that with a local folder.

Comment: I tried this first. Honestly after using eclipse with java for so long, sublime is nothing more than a text editor. I set everything up and really don't like how they did the ssh and everything with that. Very difficult to open multiple files at once because you need to keep browsing for them. I like that eclipse lets you see all the files at once if you want to.

Comment: no you don't, you can set up a local / remote folder synchronization scheme.  You don't need to browse to each file

Comment: add ok my fault then. Still feel better about eclipse though.

Answer (score 1):

If the server your working on has graphical programs installed, like gedit, you can install Xming on your local computer, then set up Putty for X11 forwarding.  That way from the remote terminal you can just run:

```
gedit myfile.php
```

and the file will appear in a graphical editor on your local machine.  Another option would be to use WinSCP to download the files to your computer and edit them locally with your favorite editor then re-upload them to the server.

Comment: Server with X.org installed and running seems very unlikely, though.

Comment: Yea we don't but this sounds cool.

Answer (score 1):

For editing files on your VM from your desktop, you might want to use an editor for your desktop that lets you save via sFTP to the VM, like Notepad++ or UltraEdit.  Both of these are feature-rich GUI driven editors, with features for programmers like keyword highlighting, syntax checking, etc., that you can run on your desktop and open/save files directly from/to a remote host.

Comment: I don't want the files on my computer, because I always have internet and its a working VM meaning other people in the company are using the site that is running off of these files, or modifying different files in the database.

Comment: The editors that I mentioned above give you options to save copies of files locally on your computer, or not.

Comment: I'm saying I don't want to do that. I want to be able to work right on the system, or not.